# sqlite3 python query with multiple variables error

Tags: python, sqlite

I looked all over for the answer to my question and could not find any good answer.... I am using python with the sqlite3 module to query a database. The problem is that I cannot get a sql query to hold multiple variables. For example...

I can get this query to work perfectly. ("wordsofar" is the variable name)

```
c.execute("SELECT word FROM wordlist WHERE word LIKE ?", wordsofar)
```

However I cannot get this code to work. ("wordsofar" and "noletter" are the variable names)

```
c.execute("SELECT word FROM wordlist WHERE word LIKE ? AND word NOT LIKE ?", (wordsofar, noletter))
```

It gives me the error: "Error binding parameter 0"

I have tried to rewrite the query so instead of "?" it is using the named convention such as shown by http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sqlite3.html (about half way down the page) but that did not solve the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank-you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line (that you say works) shows that `wordsofar` is a sequence of one element:

```
c.execute("SELECT word FROM wordlist WHERE word LIKE ?", wordsofar)
```

In this case the second line should be:

```
c.execute("SELECT word FROM wordlist WHERE word LIKE ? AND word NOT LIKE ?", 
          wordsofar + (noletter,))
```

If `noletter` is a string and `wordsofar` is a tuple (as you say in your comment).

[`execute()` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) say that the second argument is always `parameters`. If you use '?' then number of parameters (`len(parameters)`) is equal to number of '?' in the sql statement.

Comment: Actually both variables are tuples. But that fix to the second query works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You code looks fine.

The problem is in the data.  Either *wordsofar* or *noletter* is an object that sqlite3 doesn't know how to store.

One solution is to pickle the object.  Another solution is to supply converter and adapter functions.

Use [register_adapter](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.register_adapter) to register a callable to convert the custom Python type type into one of SQLite’s supported types.

The docs also describe how to supply converters to handle the reverse conversion:

> SQLite natively supports only the types TEXT, INTEGER, FLOAT, BLOB and
>   NULL. If you want to use other types you must add support for them
>   yourself. The detect_types parameter and the using custom converters
>   registered with the module-level [register_converter()](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.register_converter) function allow
>   you to easily do that.

Here's a related [SO question with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142975/keeps-getting-error-binding-parameter-0-probably-unsupported-type).

Comment: "wordsofar" is a tuple currently. And the first sql query accepts that just fine. So that is why I thought it was an issue with the code, not the data type. I currently have this line above the query to convert it into a tuple "wordsofar = (wordsofar, )" if I do not have this line and leave the variable as string data it gives the error that there were too many supplied arguments. How would I use register_adapter or register_converter() option to fix that? I am just learning python and I cannot figure out what to do from the docs.python.org site. Thank-you for the help!

Comment: Could you show the contents of the two variables and explain what you're trying to accomplish with them?  In the first instance, the first value in wordsofar is getting bound to the single "?".  In the second, you're asking to have the entire tuple bound to the first "?".

Comment: From the results I would say that in the first query the whole tuple is getting bound to the "?". There is sql wildcards in the variable making wordsofar look something like `__a__` and noletter look like `%b%` The problem is solved and it works correctly by making the query look like what @J.F. Sebastian recommended.

Comment: It is the tuple causing the problem.  Replace ``wordsofar`` with ``wordssofar[0]`` to extract the underlying string.